# How to generate serialVersionUID for Serializable?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization

I have a **class A** that extends another **class B** that implements `Serializable` interface.
I want to automatically generate the `serialVersionUID` for **class A** using the Eclipse.

If class A was the class that implements `Serializable` Eclipse will have a error compilation. Please help me generate it automatically.

class A

```
public class QueryOptionModel extends BaseModelData {



}
```

[class b - gxt api](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/extjs/gxt/2.1.1/gxt-2.1.1-javadoc.jar!/gxt-2.1.1-javadoc/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/data/BaseModelData.html)

```
public class BaseModelData implements ModelData, Serializable
```

Comment: Please provide some further details - which error do you receive?

Comment: i don't receive that's the prob

Comment: When your class's parent class extends a serializable class, |Eclipse asks you (warning) to provide a serialVersionUID. I don't get your problem

Comment: the problem is that eclipse didn't ask me to provide a serialVersionUID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a class which implements `Serializable` interface but doesn't specify a `serialVersionUID`, you'll get a warning. You can automatically ask Eclipse to fix that warning by clicking on the balloon which pops up on that line. Make sure you don't generate a random but a logical `serialVersionUID` i.e. `0` or `1` if this is the first draft of your serilizable class.

Comment: but my class extent a class that implement a the Serializable, and don't show the warning

Comment: I think you should post the code you are using. I do get a warning on my stock Eclipse installation.

Comment: Probably your compiler settings ignore this. You can change this in Eclipse: Open the properties of your project, select Java Compiler => Errors/Warnings and set the item Serializable class without serialVersionUID to Warning or Error.